# Arrays.asList to create an array from string and then omit the first word in the array

Tags: java, arrays

I know there may be other ways around this but I want to try and continue this way, I'm trying to make a simple list with a string, split as an array, and I'm trying to get an output such as:

> [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]

I'm using a HashMap with a key to put in the array and then get an array list from it afterwards with the key "mode"

currently, the output that I get is "[mode, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]" but I want to omit the key from the result, however I don't want to just do .split("mode, ")   on the output, 
I want to know if there is a way I can alter the original string:

> String test = "mode,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H";

so I can get an output as:

> [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]

and not:

[mode, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]

what I am really trying to do.. but there is the same problem and I want to counteract the problem with regex,  this is basically ideas I got from another person's code - I am confused by the regex pattern here, if someone could explain the **?<=** in the start of the pattern, it would help

```
 public class Main {


    static final Map<String, LinkedList<String>> Modes = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>(); 

    private final Pattern SET_DROPDN=Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s{0,10}set\\s{1,10}the\\s{0,10})(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);



    String test = "mode,A,B,C,D,E,F,G";


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Main main = new Main();

        main.test(" set the mode E");  //
    }




    public void test(String s)
    {

        Matcher matcher = SET_DROPDN.matcher(s);


        if(matcher.find())
        {      


            String arg1 = matcher.group(1); 
            System.out.println("mx.group(1) = " + arg1);

            String arg2 = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("mx.group(2) = " + arg2);


            for(String st:test.split(","))
            {
                Modes.put(st, new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(test.split(","))));                          
            }        

            List<String> vals = Modes.get(arg1);


            System.out.println("vals = " + vals);

            int idx = 0;

            for(String sg:vals)
            {

                if(sg.equals(arg2))
                {
                    break; //break out of this loop
                }

                idx++;


            }  

            System.out.println("Index for element = " + idx);
        }
    }

}
```

The main problem is that I want 'A' to have idx value of 0 and 'E' should have idx value of 4 - But what is happening is that 'mode' is getting the idx value of 0

Comment: seems to be if vals is guaranteed to have its first item to be something you don't want you can use the remove(0) function to remove the first item.  Throw in some validation to ensure its what you want to remove, and viola

Comment: `(?<=X)  MEANS X, via zero-width positive lookbehind` from [Java Doc for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: thanks boxed__, I should have tried the Javadoc, I was searching the wrong sources

Comment: String test = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,mode";  is actually a solution to my problem, but I think I will go with the answer below (since it does answer my original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use list.remove(0) to remove 1st element from list

```
List<String> vals = Modes.get("mode");
            vals.remove(0);

            System.out.println(vals);
```

use this code and check the output

```
 String test = "mode,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H";
         test = test.replaceAll("mode,", "");
         System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: alright well.. that works, but is there some way I could modify the original string so it won't display it? I tried something like String test = "mode=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]";  but this only gave null.. Maybe there is a way with Java regex... I'll have to look into it..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter method in guava library to filter out any value.. in this case it could be done as

```
List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(Arrays.asList(test.split(",")), Predicates.containsPattern("^\\w{1,1}$")));
```

This means it'll split the string to list and filter out any word with length more than 1. You can tweak the pattern to filter out anything..

Answer (score 0):

Another approach just removing first element and comma before it:

```
String test = "mode,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H";

int firstComma = test.indexOf(',');
String substring = test.substring(firstComma + 1);

System.out.println(substring); // this is the result
```